# How to set up C-language auto-completion in Helix text-editor?

Tags: linux, helix-editor

I decided to try new console editor instead Vim. But I'm not really experienced in this kind of stuffs. I've successfully installed Helix and even modified some features in configs.

But I've not succeed in setting up auto-completion for C.

Actually I don't understand how LSP works very well.

In official documentation there is not any specific explanations about this, as well as on YouTube and StackOverflow.

I'll be grateful for any help.

I tried this in my languages.toml file:

```
[language-server.clangd]
command = "clangd"

[[language]]
name = "c"
auto-format = true
language-servers = ["clangd"]
```

and this in my config.toml:

```
theme = "onedark"

[editor]
mouse = true
line-number = "absolute"
auto-completion = true
```